# Changing AppPool folder permissions in Azure App Service - IIS APPPOOL\MyUserName

Tags: azure, iis, permissions, nopcommerce, azure-web-app-service

I've deployed nopCommerce as an Azure App Service using the simple Web Publish option.

Having then tried to configure the installation by running the nopCommerce installer I receive the following errors.

```
The 'IIS APPPOOL\MyUserName' account is not granted with Modify permission on folder....
```

[image]

Now normally this would be a trivial fix as I would login the application IIS server and presumably grant modify permissions to the IIS APPPOOL user for the given folders. However because this is an Azure App Service, I do not believe there is any way to login to the actual VM that runs all my application instances and thereby grant permissions to the APPPOOL user.

So is there some way to work around this? Can I grant these permissions using some other means for an Azure App Service (for example using the console in Azure)?

Comment: You are supposed to use the gallery version, https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/blog/azure-web-application-gallery-on-azure-microsoft-com/

Comment: @LexLi No you're not! You're 'supposed to use' whichever deployment scenario makes sense for your use case and infact the documentation explicitly describes Web Publish as a deployment option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone curious the actual solution was creating these folders.

- wwwroot\bin
- wwwroot\log

and the files:

- installedPlugins.json
- dataSettings.json

Once I added those files/folders I was able to successfully complete the installation.

Comment: It would be nice if someone actually answered the questions as to if it is possible to modify folder permissions for an Azure App.